# Unix command to recursively copy JPG files in a complex directory tree

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I have a large directory tree structure that contains multiple JPG files in each directory root and their subsequent subdirectories. I need to recursively extract a single JPG file from each directory root and copy them all to another location whilst maintaining the same tree structure and ignoring the other files. The JPG filenames that I need to extract all are tagged with "RNav.jpg". I experimented with the cp command and wild card but I could not get it to work. I'm running Mavericks and I'm a novice when it comes to UNIX command-lines.

The existing structure is as follows: (up to 500 directories)

- VNAME/PNAME1/PNAME1_RNav.jpg
- VNAME/PNAME2/PNAME2_RNav.jpg
- VNAME/PNAME3/PNAME3_RNav.jpg
- VNAME/PNAME4/PNAME4_RNav.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `rsync -R` (`--relative`) or `--parents` in GNU cp:

```
rsync -R */*/*.RNav.jpg /path/to/target
gcp --parents */*/*RNav.jpg /path/to/target
find . -name \*RNav.jpg -exec rsync -R {} /path/to/target \;
find . -name \*RNav.jpg -exec gcp --parents {} /path/to/target \;
```

Comment: This one works!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can easily use rsync to accomplish this:

```
rsync --include "*/" --include "*RNav.jpg" --exclude "*" -am source destination
```

Based off [this page](http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/linux-copy-only-certain-filetypes-with-rsync-from-foldertree/). This includes folders and *RNav.jpg files and then excludes everything else. I've used -a instead of -r to preserve more information (my personal preference) and added -m to prevent rsync from creating any parts of the directory tree that wouldn't contain any files.

Comment: Gracias! Worked perfectly!

Comment: After further testing, I realized that it's including the other JPG files that aren't tagged with RNav.jpg. I tried varying the wildcard as follows to no avail: --exclude "*.jpg"

Comment: Huh, are you sure? I don't get that result here. Maybe the other files already exist in the destination directory? rsync won't remove them unless you add --delete-excluded (to be really clear, that would delete all files from the destination folder, except the ones ending in RNav.jpg).

Comment: The destination directory is completely empty before running the command line so I'm not sure why it's extracting and copying those other JPG files.